# Node js connecting two socket so that retrieving would be easier

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Currently now i am using io.emit where i send the event to all the connected users and in client side i check whether the id of user i emit is equal to the id of client side then the condition runs i thinks its making my code messy and bit slow is there anything i can do like connecting then in one group so when retrieving them i would be easier for me.

```
//server side
var id = 1;
io.emit('check',id);

// on client side 
socket.on('check',function(data){
var current_user_login = //getting current user login id by php
if(data == current_user_login) { 
//run some code
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put certain sockets in the same room, so that it's easy
to broadcast to all of them together. Try this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('group');
  socket.broadcast.to('group').emit('new member');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to solve this problem is to create an association between the user you want to send the data to and that user's socket so you can `.emit()` only to that particular socket.  This is much, much more efficient than sending to everyone especially when you have lots of connected sockets.

You would have to explain to us much more about how you know which socket or user you want to send to in order for us to help figure out how to do that association in your server.

socket.io has the concept of "rooms" which are groups of sockets that makes it easy for you to place a socket in a specific group and to then broadcast to a specific group of sockets.

Or, each socket has an id and each socket has access to the cookies that were present when the connection was first made, both of which can sometimes be used to identify which user you want to send to.  But, you'd have to explain how you know which user you want to send to for us to help give you an idea how to code that into your server.

Comment: its like var id = 1;
io.emit('check',id); where i send the following event to the user having id 1 so in client the user which have id equals to 1 can access the event so for that i need to send the event to all clients connected and check if the emit id is equal to the user logged in then do some stuffs

Comment: @ujwaldhakal - but how do you know which user you're trying to send to?  Do you users have an id?  Is that in a cookie?  You need to figure out how you find the specific socket for the user with that id.  I don't know how your id values work to know how you would do that.  How is a user assigned an id?

Comment: no the user id values come from the connected socket like the param of any div or hidden input field etc

Comment: @ujwaldhakal - what does "come from the connected socket" mean?  Sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding where the id values comes from and how it can be associated with a particular socket.  How is a user assigned an id?

Comment: like one user challanges the request and next accepts the req now both id should be connected to socket for the further events

Comment: @ujwaldhakal - Then, you should probably just join both user's sockets to a room and then you can just `.emit()` to that room.